# Java run x-jobs multithreaded with n threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having a class called JobManagement which has a job[] jobs and a ArrayBlockingQueue queue with the size of 2.

What i am trying to do:
I want to create for exaple 20 jobs. The Job class extends Thread and overrides the run method:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        
        setStatus(EnumStatus.inProgress);
        System.out.println(this.toString());
        System.out.println("Working...");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new AuftragException();
        }
        setStatus(EnumStatus.done);
```

I wann to fill my queue with 2 jobs, call the run method on them, and repeat until all jobs from the job[] jobs are done.

I am currently thinking of a method startWork() in the class JobManagement which does the following:

```
    for (Job j : jobs) {
        while (!queue.offer(j)) {
            queue.poll().start();

        }
```

I do not limit Java to only use 2 threads here, am i?

Edit:
Using Executor.Service with a fixed threadpool solved my issue.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)`

Comment: What is the point of the queue here? You basically run all your jobs except the last two here.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat oh wow. Didn't know that was possible... Thanks, that is exactly what i need!